# Post Id : undefined

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, async-await, fetch

In my simple project everything is OK with different API but, in [this API](https://countriesnode.herokuapp.com/v1/countries) there is a problem

Input value is:

> Post Id : undefined

And this is my code:

```
let PostShow = 
{
    render : async () => {
        let request = Utils.parseRequestURL()
        let post = await getPost(request.id)

        return /*html*/`
            <section class="section">
                <h1> Post Id : ${post.id}</h1>

            </section>
        `
    }
    , after_render: async () => {
    }
}
```

And the output value is:

> Post Id : undefined

Both, input and output, are the same. What did I do wrong?

Comment: Can you share getPost method?

Comment: Yes. let getPost = async (id) => {
    const options = {
       method: 'GET',
       headers: {
           'Content-Type': 'application/json'
       }
   };
   try {
       const response = await fetch(`https://countriesnode.herokuapp.com/v1/countries` +id, options)
       const json = await response.json();
       // console.log(json)
       return json
   } catch (err) {
       console.log('Error getting documents', err)
   }
}

Answer (score 0):

The response of this `API` do not have `id` as a property that is why it is showing `undefined`.
This is an entry in the response - 

`{
    "name": "Andorra",
    "native": "Andorra",
    "phone": "376",
    "continent": "EU",
    "capital": "Andorra la Vella",
    "currency": "EUR",
    "languages": ["ca"],
    "emoji": "",
    "emojiU": "U+1F1E6 U+1F1E9",
    "code": "AD"
}`

Try accessing other available fields like name, code etc.

Comment: name or other object  not working..please guide me how to solve this problem

Comment: post.name not working? Can you log into console the value of post and share?

Comment: GET https://countriesnode.herokuapp.com/v1/countriesaustralia 404 (Not Found)

Comment: Here why australia is appended on the URL? Can you share the url which is getting formed after request.id is captured?